# IE11 table issue, TD's not showing up

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I am using a simple table in a client project,

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>more content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in IE11, Content in TH is visible but content in TD is not. Everything is fine in source code, the table loads up fine, but all TD's are behaving like empty cells.

any clues?

For records,
- The site is on Wordpress, using Visual Composer
- For testing purposes, I created an emtpy page with table only and no specific CSS, still same issue 
- In IE11 View source, everything is fine
- OS is Win Vista

Comment: Try wrapping the rows in `<tbody>`.

Comment: Inspect the table (in chrome dev) and post a screenshot of it. So that I can see what is the problem. Alternativlely if the site is online post a link of it here

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your header row in a <thead> and your body in <tbody>.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>more content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>more content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: @user33092 Did you put everything between HTML and body tags?